# Is the sequence of items is always the same in MapOverlay?

Tags: android, android-mapview

Firstly I add markers to the overlay:

```
private MapOverlay itemizedOverlay;

Cursor items = mDbHelper.fetchAllItems();
startManagingCursor(items);

for (int i = 0; i < items.getCount(); i++) {
    items.moveToPosition(i);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(markerPoint, "", "");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
}
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

Now I need to update markers (change drawable).
Can I do:

```
Cursor items = mDbHelper.fetchAllItems();
startManagingCursor(items);

for (int i = 0; i < items.getCount(); i++) {
    items.moveToPosition(i);
    itemizedOverlay.getItem(i).setMarker();
}
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

Will `itemizedOverlay.getItem(i)` always return items in the same sequence?
Records in the database are not added/deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will itemizedOverlay.getItem(i) always return items in the same sequence?

That is up to you. You are the one implementing `getItem()`.

Comment: Oops, I was getting confused -- you implement `createItem()` on an `ItemizedOverlay`, `getItem()` on an `Adapter`. Would've been nice if they'd've kept consistent naming conventions. Anyway, the item returned by `getItem(i)` should be the one returned by `createItem(i)` for the same value `i`. However, `ItemizedOverlay` is not open source, so there is no way to validate this.